# Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) What does this error mean

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am developing an application with PhoneGap. This is the only error and the app seems to be running fine otherwise. The error comes up right at startup. I honestly have no idea what this error means or points to and would simply like to get some clarification as to what it could be. I can add code to this post but again I don't even know where to start so I am not sure what to post. Thanks